# Web API get Version Info when base url is called

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

How can i send Version Info and few other values when WebApi's base URL is called.

Ex: `http://199.169.818.513/api` is the base url for my webapi.

When i enter the url i would like to receive a response with service details like,
Web API Version,
Name of the Site where its hosted etc

Answer (score 2):

You could create an API information class like this:

```
class ApiInformation{
  public string Version{get;set;
  public string Host{get;set;}
}
```

"IHttpActionResult Index()" method in your default controller, often called "HomeController.cs".
This would then return the ApiInformation object which you will create an instance of first.

For Version, you could make use of:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

from AssemblyInfo.cs. I usually change it to
    [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]

So the last two fields are auto generated for each compile. And then manually change the major and minor fields when necessary.

To get the version, you can call

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

To get domain name(for where its served from)

```
Request.RequestUri.Host
```

Or the IP address if that makes more sense in your scenario.

Once you filled out all the fields, you return it like this

```
return(Ok(apiInfo));
```

Ok() will return the details including HTTP-200 OK status.